# formatting grep output in zshell

Tags: bash, grep, formatting, output

I'm trying to work out what I would ask grep for in the following, forgive me as I'm relatively new!

I'm trying to get it to give me a list of filenames in a folder in the format [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\;

In which each filename is a 9 digit number, and I would like it to give me a copyable list with each filename suffixed with \;

I've gotten as far as;

grep -lr "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

but I don't know how to have it format it the way I would like.

Comment: `bash` != `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

`grep -l 'PATTERN'` gives you names of the files which have the "PATTERN" in it's content. (`grep -r` does the search recursively by going into sub-directories.)

If you need the filenames (not the content) with a certain pattern, or to put it in another way, if you need to filter out the output of the `ls` command, following will do.

```
ls -1 | grep '^[0-9]\{9\}$'
```

However if you need to re-format the filtered output (putting a semicolon at the end), `grep` alone cannot handle this. There are several solutions. Following is the `sed` solution.

```
ls -1 | sed -n 's:^[0-9]\{9\}$:&;:p'
```